# Find double orthogonal complement of non-empty subset of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $D$ be a non-empty subset of Hilbert space $H$. Find $(D^\bot)^\bot$.

There was nothing about $D$ whether it is a subspace, finite or infinite dimensional.

I know that for some of these cases double orthogonal complement is equal or is a subspace of closure of $D$, but I want to systematize my knowledge.

How do I answer such question?

Would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: It is D. Everything orthogonal to all the orthogonal elements of the original space must be the original space.

Comment: Hint: For every $M \subset H$, $M^{\perp}$ is a closed linear subspace of $H$. Also, $M \subset (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$.